# Efficiently Slice Image on GPU

Tags: ios

I need to slice an image into N tiles (rects might be located anywhere and overlap), where N could potentially be quite huge. Since `CGImage` operates on the CPU and this is a performance critical operation that happens several times per second I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this on the GPU.

What's the fastest possible solution to slice an image (possibly using the GPU)?

**PS**: If it helps in any way, the image is only grayscale (array of floats between `0` and `1`). It doesn't have to be an `CGImage/UIImage`, a float array suffices.

Comment: This question and the answer so far suggest you might have better luck stepping back a level. Ask about what problem it is that motivates your desire to create many image slices per second. (Or, ask yourself if you might be committing premature optimization—are you doing something that you've *found to be slow*, or are you considering doing something that *you think might be slow*?)

Answer (score 1):

Since slicing images is basically just copying chunks of the image to a new image there is not really a way to speed up that process. Depending on what you are doing with the slices you might be able to get away with not copying the data. If you keep only the coordinates of your slices you can access the underlying storage of your original image.